Android OSM mapView.zoomToBoundingBox
I have an application that parses gpx files and displays routes on MapView. For the map I use OpenStreetMap.
private fun setBoundingBox(points: List<GeoPoint>) = with(binding){
        val latitudes = points.map { it.latitude }
        val longitudes = points.map { it.longitude }

        val boundingBox = BoundingBox(latitudes.max(), longitudes.max(), latitudes.min(), longitudes.min())
        mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, true)
        mapView.controller.setZoom(mapView.zoomLevelDouble - 0.5)
        mapView.invalidate()
    }

I need to make the map move away by BoundingBox zoom - 0.5 (for example X-0.5). The zoomToBoundingBox method does not allow this because it sets Zoom to X. If you use mapView.zoomLevelDouble - 0.5, then nothing changes , Zoom is set to X. If you turn off animation everything works, but I need animation. I understand that this is because the zoomToBoundingBox did not finish the animation. If you wait for it to finish and set mapView.controller.setZoom(mapView.zoomLevelDouble - 0.5), then Zoom jumps (for example 15->14.5->15)
